# Vertically aligning objects

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to always align these yellow outlined boxes in a vertical line in top of eachother (see image). Currently I am using this code:

```
.yellowOutline {
    display:        inline-block;
    width:          30px;
    line-height:    30px;
    border-radius:  25%;
    text-align:     center;
    border:         2px solid #ffcd55;
    position:       relative;
    left:           250px;
```

As you can see, it is moving the yellow outlined box 250 px to the right, which makes them positioned differently according to the how many pixels there is from "Today" to the right or "Yesterday" (etc) and to the right. Is there any code I  could replace this with to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: post full (for this part) html and css, please

Comment: Vertical alignment is up and down. Horizontal alignment is left and right. I believe you want horizontal, not vertical.

Comment: Please, post the code here at least to reproduce the same as the image show. Because it obviously is being caused by the size of the word at the left, so we need to see this part of code too

Comment: There are easy ways if you control the markup. The parent markup could be `display: flex` and use `justify-content: space-between` Or you could use `position: absolute` and `right: 0` Or you could use `float: right`. I would go with `display: flex` if possible

Comment: Vertical alignment is what I am looking for. Up and down. Kindly see my updated question.

Comment: @Kunukn,thanks. your answer has been the closest. so far, the only thing I can get working is this: position: absolute and right: 80% (because it is using the width of the whole screen, not from any container)

Comment: Upload the HTML too so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS there is a vertical-align property which controls how elements are set next to each other in a line or are lined up with one another.

Elements need to be set along a baseline as set by the display properties
There is an excellent codepen by Chris Coyler that demonstrates this (with actual code)

`codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/oJeAK`